# Сохранение состояния webview

Tags: android, java, webview

Есть фрагмент и в нем webview. Когда страница загрузилась, хочу, чтобы при смене ориентации экрана webview не пересоздавалось, а то утечка помяти происходит. 
Что-то я делаю не то, походу. Помогите, а то я еще молодой в этих серьезных делах.

```
public class Css_page1 extends Fragment {

    private AdView mAdView;  
    private  WebView webView;
    private TextView text;

    public Css_page1(){}

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setRetainInstance(true);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.css_page1_layout , container, false);

        text=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webtextview1);

        ConnectivityManager cn =(ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true )
        {
            webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewCss1);
            WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
                    ws.setSupportZoom(true);
                    ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            ws.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://yariko.by/site/css/css1.html");
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_internet_please, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "KShYJgLB.ttf"));
            text.setText(R.string.not_internet);
        }

mAdView = new AdView(getActivity(), AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "ca-app-pub-3888131247409491/9743088663");        
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.LayoutHome1);       
layout.addView(mAdView);
mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        return rootView;

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сохраняйте

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}
```

и восстанавливайте состояние `WebView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ругается на webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);

Лог тут: https://yadi.sk/i/XgfZNzAZdAEG2

Comment: Ааа. Мой касяк. Забыл дописать     setRetainInstance(true);...Красавчик...Спасибос за помощь..